# How to implement paging and sorting ing MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor, paging

Sorry for bothering you this morning, but I have a question want to ask all of you. How do I add paging and sorting into web page MVC 4? I searched many example for that but I couldn't make it in my project.

Here in `Controller`:

```
public ActionResult Index(int? Id, String Name)
        {

            IQueryable<ProductSubcategory> list = null;
            if (Id == null)
            {
                list = BikesDB.ProductSubcategories;
             }
            else
            {
                int id = Id.Value;
                list = BikesDB.ProductSubcategories.Where(m => m.ProductSubcategoryID == id && m.NameofBike == Name);
            }

            var bikes = list.Where(m => m.isSelected == true)
                .AsEnumerable().Select(p => new Bike { Id = p.ProductSubcategoryID, Name = p.NameofBike });
            var viewModel = new CategoriesIndexViewModel
            {
                NumberOfModel = bikes.Count(),
                NameofBike = bikes.Select(b=>b.Name).ToList(),
                Bikes = bikes.ToList()
            };
            return this.View(viewModel);
        }
```

In `.cshtml`:

```
@model AdventureCycle.ViewModels.CategoriesIndexViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Categories";
}

<h2>Categories Bikes</h2>

<p>There are @Model.NumberOfModel kind of bikes</p>

<ul>
@foreach (var bike in Model.Bikes)
 {
   <li><span> @Html.ActionLink(bike.Name, "Categories", new {id = bike.Id, name = bike.Name})</span></li>
 } 
</ul>
```

Does anyone has any suggestions for me how to do it? Thank you very much!

Comment: What did you try so far? What is the concrete problem?

Comment: @Péter I'm trying to add paging into web page, for example I have 100 products in my `Home` page and now I want to divide it into 15 or 20 products in one page, and it has 5 total pages. You know what I mean?

Answer (score 0):

You should get first 10 or 20 records first time and on some event from user get next 20 records:

```
var bikes = list.Where(m => m.isSelected == true)
                .AsEnumerable()
                .Select(p => new Bike { Id = p.ProductSubcategoryID, 
                                        Name = p.NameofBike })
                .Take(20);
```

and on click on next button get the next 20 records on the base of last id of the first 20 records.

The second approach you can do is use [**Jquery datatables**](https://datatables.net/) and it will aplly client side paging to the records, but it will get all the records in one call, that is not a good approach if you have records in a large amount.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but what I'm looking for like this [link](http://www.superstarcoders.com/blogs/posts/pager-for-asp-net-mvc.aspx)

Comment: thanks for sharing, i will use this myself as well when needed